# How can I loop through a flat JS array, turning it into a nested parent/child structure?

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to loop through a javascript array, looking for elements of interest and, for each one, make the elements in between "children" of the preceding element of interest?

Essentially, I want to go from flat data that looks like:

```
[
  {
    value: "foo",
    type: "header!"
  },
  {
    value: "bar",
    type: "normal"
  },
  {
    value: "bar",
    type: "normal"
  },
  {
    value: "foo",
    type: "header!"
  },
  {
    value: "bar",
    type: "normal"
  }
]
```

To something more like:

```
[
  {
    value: "foo",
    type: "header!",
    children: [
      {
        value: "foo",
        type: "normal"
      },
      {
        value: "bar",
        type: "normal"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: "bar",
    type: "header!",
    children: [
      {
        value: "foo",
        type: "normal"
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

I think that Array.reduce is what I need here, but I'm struggling with exactly how to make it do what I need.

So far I've tried code that looks like:

```js
const nestedArray = flatArray.map(el => {
    if(el.type === "header!") return {
        type: el.type,
        children: []
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the logic between your input and your desired output. The input does not have any element with type "normal" and value "foo", yet you have one in your output. There is also no element with type "header!" and value "bar", yet you have one in your output... What's the logic there?

Answer (score 2):

Just loop, check the type field and push it either in the main array or in the `children` of the last header:

```js
data = [
    {value: "foo", type: "header!"},
    {value: "bar", type: "normal"},
    {value: "bar", type: "normal"},
    {value: "foo", type: "header!"},
    {value: "bar", type: "normal"}
]

let tree = [], last

for (let elem of data) {
    if (elem.type === 'header!')
        tree.push(last = {...elem, children: []})
    else
        last.children.push(elem)
}

console.log(tree)
```

As a general advice, try to avoid functions like `map` and `reduce` when manipulating complex data structures. They are far less readable, harder to reason about and much slower than `for..of` loops.